# exceptions in solr

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr. I tried to install solr as per the instructions given by
Visit http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/introduction-to-apache-solr-40-with.html
while running i am getting an error like

```
collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
RequestHandler init failure
```

Anyone please help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because .. your tomcat server is not getting collection1 folder's content correctly.

Please start with a fresh copy of solr 4 and tomcat and configure whole setup again ...I followed the same site and i am able to integrate correctly.

Double check every step mentioned there.